# How to read the image data from particular axes of MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, axes, contrast

I have designed one MATLAB GUI in which there are two axes for displaying images. I am using  'imcontrast' function to adjust brightness/contrast of the images on first axes. Now, I want to store this enhanced output(brightness/contrast adjusted output) in some variable. As 'imcontrast' function does not returns the output image, so how can i get output image? or Is there any way to read image data from particular axes? I have tried with 'getimage' function but it returns the first image data contained in the Handle Graphics object (i.e previously displayed input image) and not latest brightness/contrast adjusted Image. Please help me out in saving the brightness/contrast adjusted Image given by 'imcontrast' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
imcontrast(gca) %// Perform imcontrast
waitfor(gcf); %// Wait for figure data to be updated with imcontrast
image_data = getimage(gcf);%// Store image data as image_data variable
```

**How to use within a GUI**

Just to showcase on how to use it, you can create a pushbutton with MATLAB-Guide and in it's callback function use this -

```
%// Show the image on an existing image axes of the GUI.
imshow('pout.tif') %// This image is available in MATLAB image library.

imc_figure = imcontrast(gca) %// Perform imcontrast
waitfor(imc_figure); %// Wait for the data to be updated in the current figure
image_data = getimage(gcf);%// image data stored into image_data variable

%// Open image_data on a separate figure window for verification.
%// Make sure this is the updated image.
figure,imshow(image_data)
```

**How to use as a standalone code**

```
Im = imread('cameraman.tif');%// This image is available in MATLAB image library.
h1 = imshow(Im)
h2 = imcontrast(gca); %// Perform imcontrast 
waitfor(h2); %// Wait for figure data to be updated with imcontrast 
image_data = getimage(gcf);%// Store modified image data

%// Show modified image data for verification
figure,imshow(image_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But, its not working. Even after adding waitfor(gcf) (as you suggested) getimage is still returning the previously displayed input image. Please, help me with some other alternative.

Comment: @Vikrant Well it worked for me, could you try again? Maybe close MATLAB and start the GUI again?

Comment: I tried restarting MATLAB and also tried by writing these few lines in separate matlab file.
Im = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(Im);
imcontrast(gca); %// Perform imcontrast
waitfor(gcf); %// Wait for figure data to be updated with imcontrast
image_data = getimage(gcf);%// Store image data as image_data variable
imshow(image_data);

But, it returns empty matrix in image_data variable. I have adjusted the contrast and then closed the 'Adjust contrast' window which pops up when imcontrast is executed. I even tried clicking on adjust data on 'Adjust data' window, but didn't worked

Comment: @Vikrant Please check out just added **How to use within a GUI** and **How to use as a standalone code** sections. Hope this settles it!